# Avoiding general Function type in react + typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I am looking for a rule that prevents usage of "Function" as a type

`myMethod: Function;`

I didn't find anything so I am open to suggestions :)

Comment: Are you sure it's typescript? As far as I know TS doesn't have any native generic function type. However, Flow does.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `@typescript-eslint/ban-types` rule [Rule Link](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md). But this will also ban the other default types too like `String`, `Boolean`, etc. [Link of other default banned types](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/src/rules/ban-types.ts#L56)

If you wish to only ban `Function` and disable the other bans then add this to your `.eslintrc` file.

```
"@typescript-eslint/ban-types": ["error",
    {
        "types": {
            "String": false,
            "Boolean": false,
            "Number": false,
            "Symbol": false,
            "{}": false,
            "Object": false,
            "object": false,
            "Function": true,
        },
        "extendDefaults": true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use eslint, following rule bans `Function` type

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Function` you should just put the arguments and the return type. For example `() => void`

```js
const save = (onSucessCallback: () => void) => {
  // whatever your code does
  onSucessCallback()
}
```

Comment: OP wasn't suggesting they _wanted_ to use `Function`, but that they want to specifically disallow its use.