# How to avoid general Function type in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, eslint

I'm using eslint and it states that using 'Function' as a type is unsafe.
Is there a better way of doing this, so that I don't use the function type:

I have this confirmation dialog that appears when I'm trying to delete something:

```
export class DialogConfirmationComponent {
      
  message: string = "";
  txtBtnConfirmation: string = "Confirm";

  actionConfirm: Function = () => { };
  actionCancel: Function = () => { };
}
```

And when I click on the confirm button on the html this actionConfirm Function is called.

I want it to be generic so that I can call this dialog for different components and uses, and define the action using bind on the component, like this:

```
export class ItemCardComponent {

  constructor(
      private dialog: MatDialog
  ) { }

  public openDeleteDialog(item: Item): void {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogConfirmationComponent, {
        width: '500px',
        panelClass: 'no-padding-dialog',
        autoFocus: false
      });
      dialogRef.componentInstance.message= "Are you sure?";
      dialogRef.componentInstance.txtBtnConfirmation = "Delete";
      dialogRef.componentInstance.actionConfirm = this.delete.bind(this, item);
  }

  private delete(item: Item): void {
    // ToDo: delete
  }
}
```

So far it's working, but is there a better way of doing it without using the Function type?

Comment: `() => void`...?

Comment: @caTS it doesn't work when I don't bind any functions like in this case if I cancel, it should just close and not do anything. If I use '() => void' I get an error...

Comment: Well, what error do you get?

Comment: Checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63913504/17447

Comment: @caTS it says ctx.actionCancel is not a function. The best solution I got so far is leaving it untyped and using something like: `actionCancel =  () => { return null; };`. Not sure if there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

You could use this if the function is very general and you are unsure of the number and type of parameters or the nature of the return type:
`(...args: any[]) => any`

However, if you are aware of the return type, you may use this in its place. Note that the return type in this case is void:
`(...args: any[]) => void`

If you want to boost type safety, you may also replace any with types. In this example, you are presuming that the parameters are of the type number or string and that the return type is unknown.

`(...args: (string & number)[]) => unknown`